# Error while compiling glibc from source

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, compiler-errors, glibc

I am trying to compile glibc 2.15 from source. I followed all the steps in [gnu link](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Configuring-and-compiling.html). The configuration was success but when I try to make I am getting this peculiar which is terminating the compilation. I tried searching for the error but there was no mention of it on the web.
I am doing this on `64bit Ubuntu 12.10`.

The error message is

```
'wctomb.c:59:1: error
   __EI_wctomb' aliased to external symbol '__GI_wctomb'
   make[2]: *** [/var/services/homes/abhi/ld/glibc-build/stdlib/wctomb.os] Error 1
   make[2]: Leaving directory `/var/services/homes/abhi/ld/glibc-2.15/stdlib'
   make[1]: *** [stdlib/subdir_lib] Error 2
   make[1]: Leaving directory `/var/services/homes/abhi/ld/glibc-2.15'
   make: *** [all] Error 2`
```

How do I solve this error. Any pointers or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you compiling the GNU libc, and why are you compiling such an old version (current one is 2.18)? What is your version of GCC, of the kernel, and of binutils? GNU libc is a central piece of your Ubuntu (or Linux) system that you should not replace without great caution! Unless you are an expert (but then you would not ask), you should not recompile the GNU libc and overwrite the one provided by your distribution.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I working on a project where we need to modify the libc. I just downloaded the code and trying to build it to get familiar with the build process. Can you please give me some suggestion about this error. Thanks

Comment: Then work inside a `chroot`-ed environment, use the *latest* glibc (2.18) -or maybe [MUSL libc](http://musl-libc.org/)- and ask on specific mailing list or forum e.g. on [libc-help](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-help/), etc... I am not particularly familiar with build issues on glibc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a reported bug with GCC 4.7 on Debian distro [bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14281) because of which this and other variants of this bug occurs(another is with math library).

-> Work around was to download and install GCC 4.8 (this can only be done by building from source on 12.10 Quantal currently) and then using that to build glibc.